# exiting for loop too quickly vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am brand new to programming and currently working on trying to learn vba.  I'm having an issue with a for each loop I am trying to run where I exit my loop too quickly.  I have a range that I'd like to test to see if they have certain values present and if so, I'd like to delete the column.  But it only tests the condition one time and then exits the loop.  Would definitely appreciate any help on this!

```
  For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("S1:AA1")


    If ActiveCell.Value = "Actual" Then
        ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Delete


    ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
        ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Delete


    Else: ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).Select


    End If

Exit For

Next
```

Comment: Use `cell` instead of `ActiveCell`, and there is no need to `Select`.

Comment: Also, your `Exit For` statement seems suspect, this will exit on the first cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `cell` instead of `ActiveCell`, and there is no need to `Select`.

Also, your `Exit For` statement seems suspect, this will exit on the first cell.  You generally only use an `Exit` statement when some condition has been met which requires exiting the loop *before* processing all of the items (i.e., a loop designed to find the *first* instance of *something*, etc.).

Finally, when deleting members from a collection, you need to do it in reverse order (otherwise, extraordinary measures must be taken to ensure all items are processed).

```
Dim i as Long
Dim cell as Range
For i = ActiveSheet.Range("S1:AA1").Columns.Count to 1 Step - 1
    Set cell = ActiveSheet.Range("S1:AA1").Cells(i)
    Select Case cell.Value
        Case "Actual", ""
           cell.EntireColumn.Delete
        Case Else
           'Do nothing, unless you need to do something...
    End Select
Next
```

NB: Case-sensitivity and trailing/leading spaces. If you're concerned about "ACTUAL", "actual", "AcTuAl", etc., and values like "   " and "Actual   ", you should do:

```
Select Case UCase(Trim(cell.Value))
    Case "ACTUAL", ""
...
```

Comment: I'd probably say `Next i` is better practice - good answer though - I forgot about deleting backwards!

Comment: I think `Next i` is superfluous but it probably is a best practice. I stopped using it years ago :D

Comment: `Next i` is a nice visual cue when you have nested loops at least

Comment: @Brad very true, but proper indenting (even though VBA doesn't require it) is better IMO.

Comment: oh yeah, no doubt. Never don't indent. But I'll take all the help I can get to keep things straight sometimes

Comment: Oh I hear ya on that @Brad -- what I try to do if blocks of code are getting to big, is usually break it off in to a subroutine or function call. `For i = 1 to n ... {100 lines of executable code} ... Next` then becomes `For i = 1 to n: Call SomeFunction(args, if, needed): Next i`

Comment: Thanks everyone!  That worked out perfectly for me.  Very much appreciated.